# Spock, capturing arguments and using them in other parts of the test

Tags: groovy, spock

So I want to capture arguments passed into a mock and set them so that other things in my test can use them

```
class FileServiceSpec extends Specification {

  @Shared
  FileEntity originalFileUploadEntity

  def fileRepository = Mock(FileRepository)
  def fileStorageClient = Mock(FileStorageClient)
  def fileConverter = Mock(FileConverter)
  def fileMapper = new FileMapperImpl()
  def fileService = new FileService(fileRepository, fileStorageClient, fileConverter, fileMapper)

      def"upload offline canvas file requires conversion"(){
    given: " a file that requires conversions"
    def file = fileUploadRequest("test.pptx")
    def content = "dGVzdCBmaWxl"
    def taskId = "100"

    FileEntity convertedFileUploadEntity
    FileEntity originalFileUploadEntity

    when:
    def resp = fileService.uploadOfflineCanvasUploadAndConvertedUpload(file, content, taskId);

    then:
    1 * fileConverter.convertPptxToPdf(*_) >> Base64.getDecoder().decode("convertedpdfcontent");

    //the converted file is uploaded
    1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, Base64.getDecoder().decode("convertedpdfcontent" )) >> {args ->
      convertedFileUploadEntity = FileEntity.class.cast(args[0])
      assert FileEntity.class.cast(args[0]).fileName == "test.pdf"
      assert FileEntity.class.cast(args[0]).entityName == "offline-canvas-converted-upload"
    };
    //the original file is uploaded
    1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, Base64.getDecoder().decode(content )) >> {args ->
      originalFileUploadEntity = FileEntity.class.cast(args[0])
      assert FileEntity.class.cast(args[0]).fileName == "test.pptx"
      assert FileEntity.class.cast(args[0]).entityName == "offline-canvas-upload"
    };
  }
```

As you can see, I am able to capture the argument and set its value like this           originalFileUploadEntity = FileEntity.class.cast(args[0]). However once I exit the lambda, that value goes to null again, so in the first method capture, i set it and i can see it while debugging, however in the second method argument capture, the property i set in the first method capture is now null

Answer (score 0):

In this way it must work:

```
def "upload offline canvas file requires conversion"() {
    given: " a file that requires conversions"
    def file = fileUploadRequest("test.pptx")
    def content = "dGVzdCBmaWxl"
    def taskId = "100"

    def expectedDecodedContent = Base64.getDecoder().decode("convertedpdfcontent")
    FileEntity convertedFileUploadEntity = null
    FileEntity originalFileUploadEntity = null

    when:
    def resp = fileService.uploadOfflineCanvasUploadAndConvertedUpload(file, content, taskId);

    then:
    1 * fileConverter.convertPptxToPdf(*_) >> expectedDecodedContent;

    1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, expectedDecodedContent) >> { convertedFileUploadEntity = it[0] as FileEntity }
    convertedFileUploadEntity.fileName == "test.pdf"
    convertedFileUploadEntity.entityName == "offline-canvas-converted-upload"

    1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, Base64.getDecoder().decode(content)) >> { originalFileUploadEntity = it[0] as FileEntity }
    originalFileUploadEntity.fileName == "test.pptx"
    originalFileUploadEntity.entityName == "offline-canvas-upload"
}
```

If `uploadFile` method returns `FileEntity` instance, then it does not work in your case because you does not return it from closures and you do asserts instead of it.

In this example closure returns value of `convertedFileUploadEntity`:

```
1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, expectedDecodedContent) >> { 
    convertedFileUploadEntity = it[0] as FileEntity 
}
```

Because it is the same as:

```
1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, expectedDecodedContent) >> {
    convertedFileUploadEntity = it[0] as FileEntity
    return convertedFileUploadEntity 
}
```

But in this example closure does not return it:

```
1 * fileStorageClient.uploadFile(_, expectedDecodedContent) >> { 
    convertedFileUploadEntity = it[0] as FileEntity
    assert convertedFileUploadEntity.fileName == "test.pdf" 
}
```